# How to use python to get the device file and partition number of a certain path?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, filesystems

In Unix and Unix-like OS, the storage driver is mounted in a certain path.
Is there any function in Python (3.x is better), that is able to get the name of device and partition number of a directory (for example `/ --> /dev/sda1` and `/home --> /dev/sda2`)?

Comment: with  `os.path.ismount(path)` (going back on path) you get the mount point. Then `os.statvfs(path)` could help. but I cannot go further. Maybe scanning `/etc/mtab` is still necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the source of the below code, but it did solve a similar problem I faced sometime back.
The below code uses `psutil` to get information about all the mountpoints and devices.
To install run 
`pip install psutil`

```
def disksinfo():
        values = []
        disk_partitions = psutil.disk_partitions(all=False)
        for partition in disk_partitions:
            usage = psutil.disk_usage(partition.mountpoint)
            device = {'device': partition.device,
                      'mountpoint': partition.mountpoint,
                      'fstype': partition.fstype,
                      'opts': partition.opts,
                      'total': usage.total,
                      'used': usage.used,
                      'free': usage.free,
                      'percent': usage.percent
                      }
            values.append(device)
        values = sorted(values, key=lambda device: device['device'])
        return values
```

You can tweak the code as per your requirements.

Comment: OK, thanks with the info of the device. I can easily solve the problem.